# Does this cause memory problems?

Tags: c++

Say I have the following:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo(bar);

//later on
*foo = Foo(anotherBar);
```

Since foo was allocated on the heap does this cause problems or will the memory from the temporary Foo be copied into the address of foo on the heap?

Thanks

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`*foo = Foo(anotherBar);` is no different than a regular assignment to an object of `Foo` type. `*foo` returns an lvalue of type Foo, and you are assigning to it.

Short answer: it won't cause problems, the temporary will be copied into the heap `Foo` object pointed by `foo`.

Comment: You still need to `delete foo` later on. And we're assuming `Foo`'s assignment operator is implemented correctly and frees any resources the original object may be managing.

Comment: ...or Foo overrides the new operator in a weird way or... or... or so many other things that should be considered in C++

Answer (score 2):

As long as you remember to delete foo at some point, that will not cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

If `Foo` allocates anything on the heap, it won't be deallocated, as the first instance's destructor will not be called.

Comment: Do you mean destructor instead of constructor? If it has a destructor the [C++ rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172961#4172961) suggests it ought to also have an assignment operator too because of precisely that.

Comment: bluh? yes, that's what i meant!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't be sure that the assignment operator will do the right thing, you could consider manual deletion and reconstruction without releasing the memory:

```
foo->~Foo();
foo = new (foo) Foo(anotherBar);
```

I would certainly not recommend this, and it's non-intuitive and inelegant, but I thought I put it out there just in case someone really wanted to avoid the deallocation and reallocation brought about by `delete` and a separate `new`.

Avoiding `new` altogether in favour of resource-managing containers is by far preferable, of course.

Answer (score -1):

2 ojects are being created at runtime using the same pointer.
When it points to 2nd memory location hence we have no way to access 
the first object inorder to free it back to heap, hence mem leak.

Comment: This is incorrect. The second object created is a temporary, *not* allocated via new. The first object is being dereferenced, so the assignment is not a pointer assignment. **The address the pointer points to does not get changed**